# Adding columns to my table I am getting Insertable trait Error , but those types are already use in table

Tags: rust, traits, rust-diesel, rust-diesel-mysql

Below is my table so I have added last three columns to my table  , Upon adding , the last message is occurring so when I remove those columns/fields issue gone but i need more columns in my table.

```
      `diesel::table! {
document_template_masters (id) {
    id -> Int8,
    document_template_id -> Int8,
    paragraph_font_type -> Varchar,
    paragraph_font_size_pt -> Float8,
    paragraph_spacing_pt -> Float8,
    paragraph_margin_left -> Float8,
    paragraph_margin_right -> Float8,
    paragraph_color -> Varchar,
    heading1_font_type -> Varchar,
    heading2_font_type -> Varchar,
    heading3_font_type -> Varchar,
    heading4_font_type -> Varchar,
    heading5_font_type -> Varchar,
    heading6_font_type -> Varchar,
    heading1_format -> Varchar,
    heading2_format -> Varchar,
    heading3_format -> Varchar,
    heading4_format -> Varchar,
    heading5_format -> Varchar,
    heading6_format -> Varchar,
    heading1_margin_left -> Float8,
    heading2_margin_left -> Float8,
    heading3_margin_left -> Float8,
    heading4_margin_left -> Float8,
    heading5_margin_left -> Float8,
    heading6_margin_left -> Float8,
    heading1_color -> Varchar,
    heading2_color -> Varchar,
    heading3_color -> Varchar,
    heading4_color -> Varchar,
    heading5_color -> Varchar,
    heading6_color -> Varchar,
    created_at -> Timestamptz,
    updated_at -> Timestamptz,
    deleted_at -> Nullable<Timestamptz>,
    page_type -> Nullable<Varchar>,

    justification -> Varchar,
    name -> Varchar,
    page_margin_top -> Varchar,
    page_margin_bottom -> Varchar,
    orientation -> Varchar,
    page_height -> Varchar,
    page_width -> Varchar,
    custom -> Varchar,
    page_background_color -> Varchar,
    page_columns-> Int8,
    heading1_justification -> Varchar,
    is_header -> Bool,
    header_free_text_L -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    header_free_text_R -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    header_free_text_C -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    header_pageno_L -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    header_pageno_R -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    header_pageno_C -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    page_number_style -> Varchar,
    header_styles_L-> Nullable<Varchar>,
    header_styles_R -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    header_styles_C -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    header_styles_L_color -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    header_styles_R_color -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    header_styles_C_color -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    header_image_L -> Nullable<Int8>,
    header_image_R -> Nullable<Int8>,
    header_image_C -> Nullable<Int8>,


    

}
```

}`

`(Serialize, Deserialize, Insertable, Clone, PartialEq)] ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait` diesel::Insertableschema::document_template_masters::table `is not implemented for  std::option::Option<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<schema::document_template_masters::columns::header_font_size_L, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<BigInt>, &i64>>>, std::option::Option<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<schema::document_template_masters::columns::header_font_size_R, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<BigInt>, &i64>>>, std::option::Option<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<schema::document_template_masters::columns::header_font_size_C, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<BigInt>, &i64>>`

**I trouble shoot alot with the help of different issues on github but not find any solution yet **

Comment: You've likely hit a column limit in diesel here. Assuming you've already enabled the `64-columns-feature` you might now need the `128-columns-feature`.

Comment: Thank you I have configured and added 128-columns-feature